# How to make a request in a localhost mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql and request. I want to make a request in my localhost server. I just need to know how to make the get request into the localhost server because I don't understand how, I'm running into a continuous loop.

```
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'virtual_currency_price'
});
```

Request:

```
router.get('/getprice', function(req, res){
 request(connection, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){


    }
 });
});
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this but I'm failing very miserably

The table I'm trying to GET from is called "price" and I will be using the datetime to fetch certain prices.

Answer (score 0):

After you establish a connection with your server you can use it to fetch data from database. You don't need to make a request using the module, just use the connection directly to execute queries as below:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'virtual_currency_price'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from price', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(rows);
});

connection.end();
```

It's recommended that you create a pool of connections instead and reuse them in your app instead of creating it every time you need to access the DB.

See the [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) from github.